# Files from folder with ignored content is deleted when pushing to Herku

Tags: php, git, heroku

I have a PHP site which pushed to Heroku through git.
The app saves pictures to a folder which contains a .gitignore:

```
*

!.gitignore
```

The folder is pushed successfully to the server and I managed to save pictures in it.
But the folder gets empty every time I push new changes to Herku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynos have an [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) which doesn't persist across deploys (by design).

If you intend to save files I would look at saving them to Amazon S3 using a background process.